# How to lock Oracle table using select statement in C# ? I tried using NOLOCK but still cannot lock.I'm getting conflicts while using tasks

Tags: c#, oracle, winforms

First, I am checking the table then update the row. Within this process I am getting a conflict. Like I have Windows Forms, if I open 2 windows the same application both are working at the same time. I suspect if I use Lock can able to avoid this type of conflict. Web very easy but Windows Forms I don't know. I am using Oracle.

```
public Tasks GetTaskDetails()
{
        Tasks tasks = new Tasks();

        DataLayer datalayer = new DataLayer(_strConn);
        OracleCommand ocdSelect = new OracleCommand();

        Sqlquery = "SELECT * FROM basictasks NOLOCK WHERE STATUS = 1 and rownum = 1 order by TASKID";

        ocdSelect.CommandText = Sqlquery;

        DataTable dt = datalayer.GetResultDT(ocdSelect, false);

        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
           tasks.TaskID = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0]["TASKID"]);
           tasks.MechineName = dt.Rows[0]["MACHINENAME"].ToString();
           tasks.Parameters = dt.Rows[0]["PARAMETERS"].ToString();
           tasks.TaskName = dt.Rows[0]["TASKNAME"].ToString();
           tasks.Description = dt.Rows[0]["DESCRIPTION"].ToString();
           tasks.Status = 2;
           tasks.StartTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt");
           tasks.FinishJob = false;

           UpdateTaskDetails(tasks);

           return tasks;
       }           

       return null; 
}

public void UpdateTaskDetails(Tasks task)
{
        DataLayer datalayer = new DataLayer(_strConn);

        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(); 

        try
        {
            Sqlquery = "BEGIN ";

            if (task.FinishJob)
                Sqlquery += string.Format("UPDATE basictasks SET STATUS = " + task.Status + ", ENDTIME = SYSDATE,REMARK = '" + task.Remarks + "' WHERE TASKID = " + task.TaskID + " ;");
            else
                Sqlquery += string.Format("UPDATE basictasks SET STATUS = " + task.Status + ", STARTTIME = SYSDATE WHERE TASKID = " + task.TaskID + " ;");

            Sqlquery += " END;";

            datalayer.TableOperation_BySQL(Sqlquery, true);

            if (datalayer != null)

                datalayer.CheckTransaction(true); 
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
        }
}
```

Comment: `select ... from ... for update nowait`?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Yes, it seems working. can able to lock but how can I commit. meaning  after the update I need to commit.now cannot able to update because table is lock.

Comment: 1. Start transaction (`OracleTransaction`) 2. Execute `select ... from ... for update nowait` within this transaction (the table is locked now) 3. Execute `update` within the transaction 4. Commit the transaction (and you `update` commited and lock released)

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Ok I will try now.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko It's working Thanks. Anyway, I got an exception (ORA-00054: resource busy and acquire with NOWAIT specified or timeout). but I can i  ignore it. Thanks